# Webpack - Reading from "node:XXX" is not handled by plugins

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, uri

I've got a typescript project that I'm building using Webpack.  I'm fairly new to web development in general, so forgive me if my terminology isn't always correct.

I'm trying to use the following npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodewikiaapi

Here are the steps that I followed (I've also done much troubleshooting an tried many webpack configuration changes with no luck):

1. install the package via `npm install --save-dev nodewikiaapi`
2. include it in my TS file like so: `import WikiaAPI from 'nodewikiaapi'`
3. try to compile, and I get a few instances of the the following error (or similar, with different variations on "node:XXX"):

```
Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:zlib" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
    at C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:832:25
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Object.processResource (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:829:8)
    at processResource (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:220:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:171:10)
    at runLoaders (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:398:2)
    at NormalModule._doBuild (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:819:3)
    at NormalModule.build (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:963:15)
    at C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1371:12
    at NormalModule.needBuild (C:\Users\carso\Documents\Programming\TolkienExplorer_Web\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:1253:32)
 @ ./node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js 11:0-29 297:11-28 298:17-34 303:22-39 325:24-42 331:24-45 354:22-49
 @ ./node_modules/nodewikiaapi/src/main.js 3:0-30 201:29-34
 @ ./static/src/index.ts 4:0-36 39:24-32
```

I've tried many things, including installing the [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin) and then including the following in my webpack.config.js:

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

It's very possible that I've been missing some key detail though.

- Do I need to change my import statement? `import WikiaAPI from 'nodewikiaapi'`
- Do I need to add some sort external to my webpack config?
- Do I need to include the node plugin in webpack differently?
- Something else altogether?

Comment: Any update on this problem? Facing the same issue